# Host a public wiki website: how to make every contributors' content to be licensed under CC-SA automatically?

Tags: internet, terms-of-service, creative-commons

I'm trying to host a wiki website which is similar to Wikipedia: all contents licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License. Besides putting a footnote at each page to explicitly declare the license, what and where should I put the legal language to inform that every contributor must contribute under this same license (and if they do contribute, they automatically agree with it)?

Comment: Does the software require those who edit be logged in using an account? Can you control the account creation process?

Comment: @JasonAller Yes, they must log in. But the registration is public.

Comment: @JasonAller I think you mean to acknowledge users about it when they create the accounts. But I don't understand why the standard MediaWiki does not provide such a feature to add an acknowledgement when creating the accounts. Also, Wikipedia itself does not use this way. These really make me confused.

Comment: If you edit something in Wikipedia, it says near the textarea: "Work submitted to Wikipedia can be edited, used, and redistributed—by anyone—subject to [certain terms and conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of every edit screen on Wikipedia, above the "save page" button, it says:

> By clicking the "Save page" button, you agree to the [Terms of Use](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use) and you irrevocably agree to release your contribution under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) and the [GFDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_the_GNU_Free_Documentation_License) with the understanding that a hyperlink or URL is sufficient for CC BY-SA 3.0 attribution.

If you are asking for technical details on how to show that on a MediaWiki installation, that question could probably be better asked at another site. Regardless, on a standard MediaWiki installation, that text may be found and modified at the [[MediaWiki:Copyrightwarning2]] (sometimes [[MediaWiki:Copyrightwarning]]) page of the wiki.

Comment: Also, you would do good by setting $wgRightsPage $wgRightsUrl $wgRightsText